# Getting the absolute path to a database

Tags: java, path

I'm trying to change the absolute path to a relative path to a database, so that the application also runs on other systems without having to change the file path in the DatabaseConnection class.
My current DatabaseConnection constructor looks like this:

```
public DatabaseConnection(){
        Path defaultPath = Paths.get("C:\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\wuetunes\\src\\jpp\\wuetunes\\main\\resources\\database\\medialibrary.db");
        this.path = defaultPath;

        }
```

The project structure looks like this:

[image: Project Structure]

I've already tried some approaches that were discussed here (`.toAbsolutePath`, `.toRelativePath`, `.toCannonicalPath`), but nothing seems to work.

The latest attempt gave the following output:

```
C:\wuetunes\src\jpp\wuetunes\main\resources\database\medialibrary.db
```

Would appreciate help :)

Comment: Hello @Phil try [this link](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-load-file-from-resources-directory/) I think this will help you.

Comment: So database will be inside jar file when deployed? As far as I know it is possible (depends on DB) but database will be read only.